# easy way to select mesh stripe

Tags: selection-tools

I seek way to make stripe selection.
I googled, but it not found.
so I use "checker deselect" to one liner faces mesh and expand it.
is there more easy way or add-on?

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots or elaborate more?

Comment: this is my twitter tweet

Comment: sorry , I pressed enter without content

Comment: https://twitter.com/sh1kuro/status/779518395423207425

Comment: this is my tweet .